# How to add this repo to yast in openSUSE?

Tags: linux, opensuse, zypper

Following [these instructions](https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/2.0/building.html#windows-installer-build-cross-compile) I'm trying to build the sync client for owncloud. Since building the client installer for Windows is only officially supported on openSUSE I installed openSUSE in Virtualbox.

I now need to "*add the following repository using YaST or zypper ar*" using the following command:

```
zypper ar https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/isv:ownCloud:toolchains:mingw:win32:stable
```

So I copy pasted this command into the terminal, but I get an error, saying:

> If only one argument is used, it must be a URI pointing to a .repo
>   file.

The url is obviously not pointing directly to a `.repo` file, but to a website. I'm not really familiar with opensuse, so I'm unsure of what I'm looking for.

Does anybody know how I can adjust this to get it working? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I found the answer. In the end I found the link by opening the link in the command,

click the "Repositories" tab
click the "Go to download repository" link under my version of openSUSE (openSUSE_Leap_42.1 for me)

There the file is listed. Click on the file and then copy the link from the browser address bar and run it with `zypper ar`. For me it turned out to be:

```
zypper ar http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/toolchains:/mingw:/win32:/stable/openSUSE_Leap_42.1/isv:ownCloud:toolchains:mingw:win32:stable.repo
```

I hope this someday helps someone else with the same problem